# HSQLDB: Encountered a duplicated sql alias

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hsqldb

When I execute this query using a self-join from my java program

```
Query query = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT DISTINCT * " +
            "FROM lerneinheit AS le1 JOIN lerneinheit AS le2  " +
            "ON le1.datum = le2.datum AND le1.pid = le2.pid " +
            " WHERE " +
            "  le1.datum BETWEEN  '2016-10-20' AND '2016-10-20'  AND " +
            "  le1.pid = 3 AND " +
            "  (le1.abgesagtrechtzeitig = false OR  le1.nichtabgesagt = true OR le1.erschienen=true) AND " +
            "  (le2.abgesagtrechtzeitig = false OR  le2.nichtabgesagt = true OR le2.erschienen=true) AND " +
            "  le1.lernid!= le2.lernid AND " +
            "  (le2.beginn+1 BETWEEN le1.beginn AND le1.ende OR le2.ende-1 BETWEEN le1.beginn AND le1.ende) " +
            " ORDER BY le1.beginn");
```

I get the following error:

```
org.hibernate.loader.custom.NonUniqueDiscoveredSqlAliasException: Encountered a duplicated sql alias [LERNID] during auto-discovery of a native-sql query
```

Although it works fine if I do this from phpAdmin. Everything I found on that topic wasn't helpful at all. Anyone got any idea how to solve that?

Comment: Instead of `SELECT DISTINCT *`, use the name of all the columns that you actually require. Use column aliases to distinguish between the same column from the two table aliases.

Comment: @fredt My intention was to get a list managed of Lerneinheit-Objects. But it seems I will use this query to get all the ids and in another function I try to retrieve the objects by their ids.

Comment: Even so, you don't want two objects in each row of the SELECT. You can try `SELECT DISTINCT le1.* FROM ...`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but the HQL equivalent for `!=` is `<>`, so you should write `"le1.lernid <> le2.lernid AND"`

And by the way I recommend :

```
Query query = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT DISTINCT * " +
        "FROM lerneinheit AS le1 JOIN lerneinheit AS le2  " +
        "ON le1.datum = le2.datum AND le1.pid = le2.pid " +
        " WHERE " +
        "  le1.datum BETWEEN :dateMin AND :dateMax  AND " +
        "  le1.pid = :le1Pid AND " +
        "  (le1.abgesagtrechtzeitig = false OR  le1.nichtabgesagt = true OR le1.erschienen = true) AND " +
        "  (le2.abgesagtrechtzeitig = false OR  le2.nichtabgesagt = true OR le2.erschienen = true) AND " +
        "  le1.lernid != le2.lernid AND " +
        "  (le2.beginn + 1 BETWEEN le1.beginn AND le1.ende OR le2.ende - 1 BETWEEN le1.beginn AND le1.ende) " +
        " ORDER BY le1.beginn");
query.setParametter("dateMin", "2016-10-20"); 
query.setParametter("dateMax", "2016-10-20"); 
query.setParametter("le1Pid", 3);
```

Comment: Thanks. I actually use query.setParametter. But I hardcoded it for testing purposes.

Answer (score 1):

It may occurred when there are two or more column/alias exists with the SAME NAME in your select query.
Like...

```
Select A.NAME, A.ADDRESS, B.NAME, B.AGE from TABLE_A A join TABLE_B B on A.SOME_ID = B.SOME_ID;
```

Encountered a duplicated sql alias [NAME] during auto-discovery of a native-sql query will show.